# Facebook Login pop-up domains, ports, and protocols must match

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

No matter what I do I get repeated javascript errors in chrome after the facebook-login box pops up.

I am using just the bare minimum login script provided on the FB example site.  I've googled this till I'm blue in the face and can't seem to find a solution that actually works for the current version of the Javascript API.  Here's my code:

My Facebook Login Page

```
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'MYAPPID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true,
        channelUrl:'http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/channel.html'
     });
       </script>

  <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
</body>
```

I of course have MyAPPID and myDomain with the proper info.

Any help/insight would be appreciated as this is driving me nuts and I have quite a few hours into it.  Thanks all!

Comment: What URL are you accessing the page from?  Does it include www?

Comment: No, the URL is actually a subdomain.  My Channel URL matches it.